# Laravel project routing is producing errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am creating an application to be hosted on a server, and I used .htaccess however the first page that load which is usually the login screen(whose path is in my resources folder)has change to the public folder and I click anywhere else as everything is linking to the public folder, which is not right as its supposed to be in the resources folder... the app works fine, its just the routing that's giving me an issue so when i click anywhere else it says, 'the requested url can not be found on server'

I also tried putting the view folder into the public folder and routing there

my homepage is set to:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});
```

but this gets an error when moved to the public folder, the error reads,

```
InvalidArgumentException
View [auth.login] not found.
```

Comment: `View [auth.login] not found.` read this please

Comment: yes @KamleshPaul, but how do I route this then?

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#introduction

Comment: `/view/auth/login.blade.php` file is not found it is showing

Comment: You have laravel-8?

Comment: yes I am currently using that

Answer (score 0):

Clear your caches and restart your server:

```
composer dump-autoload;
//---Flush the application cache
php artisan cache:clear;
//---Remove the configuration cache file
php artisan config:cache;
php artisan config:clear;
//---Remove Routes Cache
php artisan route:clear;
```

Comment: Go to bootstrap/cache and rename config.php to config.php_

Comment: I dont have a config.php in bootstrap... only services and packages

Comment: Is there a laravel/bootstrap/cache folder in your project?

Comment: i have just got a bootstrap folder under the app folder, and the laravel folder which has a bootstrap but no cache

Comment: How about running **php artisan make:auth**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231101/discussion-between-user15181144-and-hedayatullah-sarwary).